# Vue.js/Webpack - plugin.apply is not a function

Tags: filter, webpack, vue.js

Trying to get a custom filter to load with Vue and Webpack.  The main part for my Vue component works fine but trying to load the filter results in the `plugin.apply is not a function` error being thrown.

I current have within my `entry.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(require('./filters.js'));
import News from './news.vue';

//Vue News
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { News }
});
```

Within the `filters.js` file is:

```
export default {
  filters: {
    reverse: function(value) {
      return value.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
  }
};
```

Docs seem a little thin and Google isn't helping much. Anybody able to shed any light on this?

Thanks

Comment: can you upload an [mcve] ? a single jsfiddle is enough.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you are missing an `install` method in filters.js.

http://vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin

But if `reverse` is your only filter, you could just set it:

```
Vue.filter('reverse', function (value) {
    return value.split('').reverse().join('');
});
```